# How to receive key/value pair from Firebase Cloud Massaging console in Unity Android project?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to be able to send push notifications from firebase console to the users (I know, that this is only possible when the app is not in stopped mode). In the console there are fields for putting data (key, value). 
[Screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/7Tq2ve2PChkZiw)

In my C# Unity script I have this code:

```
public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Message.Data.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in
                 e.Message.Data)
        {
            if (item.Key == "bonus")
            {
                GraphicComponents gc = FindObjectOfType(typeof(GraphicComponents)) as GraphicComponents;
                gc.AddMoney(int.Parse(item.Value));
            }
        }
    }
```

I receive notifications, but OnMessageReceived does not seem to get called, and I do not get parameters from it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show the full code .. why/where should `OnMessageReceived` get called?

Comment: I`ve created a script called FirebaseManager and put it into the scene. It (currently) contains analytics events and cloud messaging code, here is a full script: https://pastebin.com/6N89fbNN OnMessageReceived is supposed to get called automatically when notification arrives if I am correct.